# AWS S3 put-bucket-encryption operation failed with InvalidArgument error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying to enable default server-side encryption for s3 bucket. However, the command fails with the following error:

```
[root@dcm-development s3]# aws --profile S3-es-xx-xx-xx-test --endpoint-url https://es-xx-xx-z2.eecloud.xx.net s3api put-bucket-encryption  --bucket bucketname --server-side-encryption-configuration '{"Rules": [{"ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {"SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"}}]}'
An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketEncryption operation: Unknown
```

awscli / Python version:

```
root@e3a8f6bbbdbc:/app# aws --version
aws-cli/1.18.117 Python/3.6.5 Linux/3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.17.40
```

I would really appreciate if someone can point out the mistake here. Other operations are working fine such as: put-bucket-policy, delete-bucket-policy, etc.

Comment: What endpoint is that `--endpoint-url https://es-xx-xx-z2.eecloud.xx.net`? Its not AWS.

Comment: It’s our corporate cloud(Openstack) url which provides aws s3 out of the box with every account. This is our aws endpoint. As I mentioned it’s working for all other calls

Comment: Are you sure openstack supports encryption? I don't see such operation in its [docs](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/s3_compat.html).